# sp_send_email sending stored proc variable result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was given some lengthy code that in essence builds a long string and was tasked with being able to get this long string sent via t-sql email. The code is over 1300 lines long and they don't want me to rewrite the code. I was able to convince them to let me turn it into a stored procedure which I did and that works fine.

My question is, is there a way to capture the "Message" tab results and send them out via the sp_send_email stored procedure?

So if, for example, the message tab says:

```
DB Instance: SqlSvrName\Instance

Timestamp: Apr  7 2015  2:21PM

QATech: DomainName\Name


CLAIMS TASKS CLEAN UP

1.0 Delete Duplicated Tasks

Claims Tasks That Have Duplicates

1 Claims Have Duplicated Tasks



1.1 Duplicate Removal 1

0 Tasks Deleted

1.1 Duplicate Removal 1 Complete



1.2 Duplicate Removal 2

0 Tasks Deleted

1.2 Duplicate Removal 2 Complete



1.3 Duplicate Removal 3

0 Tasks Deleted

1.3 Duplicate Removal 3 Complete
```

Comment: None that I know of.   The only way I know is to populate a string variable as you go.

Comment: I am concatenating a variable within the stored procedure.  I use a PRINT @MR at the end to get those results as show above.  If I could get those results captured for an email, that would make my day.

Comment: Well then instead of doing PRINT MR, send an email using MR as the body.   However, this has to be done from within the stored proc code.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your stored procedure to use @MR as an OUTPUT parameter